# stopEvent() not working on drag event

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a container that I made draggable with this in its config :

```
draggable: {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  constraint: {
      min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      max: { x: parseInt(screen.width-57), y: 0 }
  },
  listeners: {
    dragstart: function(panel, e, offset){

    },
    drag: function(panel, e, offset){

    },
    dragend: function(panel, e, offset){

    },
    scope: this
  },
}
```

It's work fine. Now I would like to prevent the user from dragging the panel when the drag event is being fired. It might sound stupid but, this is to prevent the user to drag the panel directly, he would have to put his finger on the toolbar to drag the panel.

I've already tried a few things like

```
return false;
e.stopEvent();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

But none of them worked. Does anyone have an idea why ?

Comment: Did you try `panel.firevent('dragend')` or its ilk in the `dragstart` or `drag` event?

Comment: I don't think the firevent function can work on a panel object, can it ?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-fireEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the dragstart event to

```
dragstart: {
  fn: function(){

  },
  order: 'before'
},
```

and `return false;` worked fine...